# Yii2 How to remove site/index and page parameter from url

Tags: pagination, yii2

I am using pagination on default page,i.e, on site/index in yii2. So the URL generated by linker for paginations looks like this

```
domain.com/site/index?page=1
```

I want to remove site/index and page parameter so that it looks like as follows

```
domain.com/1
```

I tried writing rule in URL manager in config file like this

```
'site/index/<page:\d+>' => 'site/index'
```

This made the url like as follows

```
domain.com/site/index/1
```

So to remove site/index as well, I set route of pagination to '/' like this

```
$pagination->route = '/';
```

This removed site/index from URL but this again changed the URL to look like

```
domain.com/?page=1
```

I tried changing rule in URL manager like this

```
'/<page:\d+>' =>'site/index';
```

But the URL remained the same. My question is how to make it look like

```
domain.com/1
```

I am using Yii2 advanced template and have enabled strict parsing in URL manager.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working on my local machine using the following component configuration:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'baseUrl' => 'http://example.dev',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'pattern' => '<page:\d+>',
            'route' => 'site/index'
        ]
    ],
]
```

and SiteController:

```
public function actionIndex($page=NULL)
{
    var_dump($page);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this configuration didn't work for me. I am getting a (#404) error page. Maybe because I have `'enableStrictParsing'` set to `true` in URL manager.

Comment: I don't see why that would be an issue - you could temporarily set 'enableStrictParsing' to false in order to verify whether that is an issue. Have you ensured that you accept $page as a parameter to your action?