# Yii2 remove site/index from url

Tags: yii, yii2

I use the Yii2 framework and want to remove `site/index` from my URLs.

Right now I have the following URL

```
example.com/site/index
```

but would like to change it to simple

```
example.com
```

I tried the following approach [Yii2 How to remove site/index and page parameter from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272745/yii2-how-to-remove-site-index-and-page-parameter-from-url) but it doesn't work.

Could you please suggest how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add rule for empty path at the beginning of your rules:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [
        '' => 'site/index', 
        // rest of rules
    ], 
],
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the question also asked at [Yii2: Remove controller from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354593/yii2-remove-controller-from-url)

I ran into problems and I had to use the Yii2 resources as https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/enable-pretty-urls/

and this is what I got

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<action>'=>'site/<action>', 
            '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ], 
    ],
```

Comment: The additional parameters is to take care of the other unnamed controllers.